# Deserialize Json with pagination

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

I use retailCrm .Net library (https://github.com/retailcrm/api-client-dotnet)  , where I get some users. So the method where I get users in Json format next:

```
Retailcrm.Versions.V4.Client api = new Retailcrm.Versions.V4.Client(product.SiteName, product.AccessToken);
                Dictionary<string, object> filteredOrders = new Dictionary<string, object>
               {
                { "extendedStatus", "complete" },
                { "statusUpdatedAtFrom", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")},
                { "statusUpdatedAtTo", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}
               };

                Response responseFiltered = api.OrdersList(filteredOrders, 1, 100);
```

You can see method `api.OrdersList` This code return me filtered users , but there is second parameter(it is current page), it has pagination (each page have  some count of users). For now it is "hardcode" because I get users only from first page. How to get users from all pages in one time? P.S. I deserizalize JSON in model , and Model has next fields.

```
public class Pagination
    {
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int totalCount { get; set; }
        public int currentPage { get; set; }
        public int totalPageCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide json output that you want to deserizalize , that will help us understand and answer your question better

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about JSON but more about pagination of the results from RetailCRM.